# How do I set the dimensions of OpenShot images?

Tags: video-editor, openshot

For reasons I can't seem to divine, when I export images from OpenShot they are consistently 320x240, even if the originating video is 2 or 3 times that size. I've tried using the "Convert to Image Sequence" dialog and the Export to Image Sequence option in "Export Video ..." and I keep getting thumbnails. I can't find a preference that will export larger images.

When I do `File > Export Video ... > Advanced` and Choose "Export to: Image Sequence" I even see that the Profile options are set to 720 x 480 and I'm still getting 320pixel images when I export.

Comment: Hello, did you solve this?

Comment: No, I gave up. Should probably just close it.